# Clean Conditional Formatting (Excel VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I apologize if this has been answered already but I was unable to find it. Here's what I want: We all know that deleting ranges, rows, and columns will split conditional formatting and make it hideous. I'd like to create a personal macro that:

```
1.) Searches through all existing Conditional Formatting in the active sheet
2.) Recognizes duplicates based on their condition and format result
3.) Finds the leftmost column and highest row in all duplicates
4.) Finds the rightmost column and lowest row in all duplicates
5.) Determines a broadened Range using those four values
6.) Remembers the condition and format
7.) Deletes all duplicates
8.) Recreates the Conditional Format over the broadened Range
9.) Repeats until no more duplicates are found
10) Outputs how many duplicates were deleted in a MsgBox
```

I'm 50% confident I could do this myself, but I have a feeling I'll need to learn how to work with array variables. (Of which I'm completely ignorant and thus terrified) So if anyone has already created this, then I *beg* you to share your genius. Or if anyone thinks they can whip this out, I offer you the chance to create what might become one of if not **the** most commonly included tool of the entire population of personal macro users (Right up there with Ctrl+Shift+V).

Or if nobody has or wants to, then maybe a few tips??? C'mon throw me a bone here!

Comment: It sounds as if what you want to do is remove the duplicates and count how many.  What does Conditional Formatting have to do with that?  Just Define your range (plenty of posts on SO as to how to do that); Count the entries in that range; execute the `range.removeduplicates` method, and count again.  Report the difference in your message box. Might be different if you don't want to leave the Uniques behind, but its not really clear from your post.

Comment: Start with the macro recorder, modify & delete some conditional formatting and use the resulting code as your starting point. Then edit your post to include the code.

Comment: ChipsLetten: Thanks for replying and double-thanks for understanding my post! I was hoping someone may have already designed this tool and could just give it to me. I don't mind starting from scratch but I thought it wouldn't hurt to ask if someone's already "invented the wheel" before I start.

Comment: I'm actually very surprised that this isn't already a mainstay in most peoples' personal macro arsenal. I absolutely hate having to delete dozens of duplicate conditional formatting items every time my coworkers ignore the "Paste Values Only" rule. Am I a freak here? Do other people like doing that?

Comment: I don't like cleaning them either; a little utility might be useful. I'll start looking into it

Comment: I don't know what you look like Paul, but I bet you have a halo for a hat!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This removes duplicate sets of conditional formatting rules created when copying and pasting rows:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub resetConditionalFormatting()

    Const F_ROW As Long = 2
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ur As Range, maxCol As Long, maxRow As Long, thisCol As Long
    Dim colRng As Range, fcCol As Range, fcCount As Long, fcAdr As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set ur = ws.UsedRange
    maxRow = ur.Rows.Count
    maxCol = ur.Columns.Count

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each colRng In ws.Columns
        If colRng.Column > maxCol Then Exit For
        thisCol = thisCol + 1
        Set fcCol = ws.Range(ws.Cells(F_ROW, thisCol), ws.Cells(maxRow, thisCol))
        With colRng.FormatConditions
            If .Count > 0 Then
                fcCount = 1
                fcAdr = .Item(fcCount).AppliesTo.Address

                While fcCount <= .Count
                    If .Item(fcCount).AppliesTo.Address = fcAdr Then
                        .Item(fcCount).ModifyAppliesToRange fcCol
                        fcCount = fcCount + 1
                    Else
                        .Item(fcCount).Delete
                    End If
                Wend

            End If
        End With
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

.

At high level:

- It goes through each column of the used range of the active sheet
- Determines duplicates based on sets of addresses
- If it finds multiple sets:

  - For the first set - it updates the AppliesTo range to (firstRow:lastRow)
  - Deletes all other sets

(a duplicate counter can be added after the .Delete statement)

---

**Test file**

Initial rules:

[image: Initial rules]

After copying and pasting the last 2 rows, twice:

[image: After copying and pasting the last 2 rows twice]

After cleanup:

[image]

---

Notes:

- There are 14 different types of rules and many properties are different
- Not all types have .Formula or .Formula1, or even the same formatting properties
- Types can be seen in the test file or [this Microsoft page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837832.aspx)

Comment: Paul, this is amazing. You are amazing. I'll start putting it to work and let you know if I come across any situations that the code can't handle.

Comment: I'm glad you like it ane, but it doesn't meet all your initial requirements. It's just an initial attempt at automating the basic task of removing duplicates **given that each column is only supposed to have one single rule defined** - if there are multiple rules defined for the same column it will delete all except the first so only use it for straightforward files. To make it as generic as possible the criteria for finding duplicates become extremely complex as there are 14 types of rules and they don't have the same properties like Formula1, formatting, etc

Comment: It's good that you are so perseverant :) I'll give a hint in one of my previous attempts which I abandoned because of complexity - I'll place the code in a new answer

Comment: Still it's a great start! I'm much more resourceful than I am knowledgeable, so this is perfect for me. I think your column approach can be used on rows as well for a two dimensional evaluation. Also, if I make the For Each evaluation remember data in an array instead of delete, then I can simplify the array, delete all conditions, and decode the array back into conditions. It sounds like an "earbuds in, everyone out" kind of project, but I'm excited! (Thought I saw a typo in my last comment and went past the five minutes I had to revise it)

Answer (score 2):

Here's my answer to this question.  I have only implemented it for conditional formatting that uses a formula as I rarely use the other conditional format types.  It's also available as an add-in from my personal website: [MergeConditionalFormatting v1.2](https://rath.ca/Misc/VBA/Excel/MergeConditionalFormatting%20v1.2.zip)

Here's the code:

```
'''
' MergeConditionalFormatting - Add-in to merge conditional formatting.
' Author: Christopher Rath <christopher@rath.ca>
' Date: 2020-12-17
' Version: 1.0
' Archived at: http://www.rath.ca/Misc/VBA/
' Copyright © 2020 Christopher Rath
' Distributed under the GNU Lesser General Public License v2.1
' Warranty: None, see the license.
'''
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

' See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.formatcondition

Public Sub MergeCF()
    Dim cfBase As Object
    Dim cfCmp As Object
    Dim iBase, iCmp As Integer
    Dim delCount As Integer
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    delCount = 0
    
    With ActiveSheet.Cells
        'Debug.Print "Base", "Applies To", "Type", "Formula", "|", "Match", "|", "Cmp", "Applies To", "Type", "Formula"
        iBase = 1
        Do While iBase <= .FormatConditions.Count
            Set cfBase = .FormatConditions.Item(iBase)
            
            Application.StatusBar = "Checking FormatCondition " & iBase
            
            If (cfBase.Type = xlCellValue) Or (cfBase.Type = xlExpression) Then
                For iCmp = .FormatConditions.Count To (iBase + 1) Step -1
                    Application.StatusBar = "Checking FormatCondition " & iBase & " to " & iCmp
                
                    Set cfCmp = .FormatConditions.Item(iCmp)
                    
                    'Debug.Print iBase, cfBase.AppliesTo.Address(, , xlR1C1), cfBase.Type, _
                    '            Application.ConvertFormula(cfBase.Formula1, xlA1, xlR1C1, , _
                    '                                       cfBase.AppliesTo.Cells(1, 1)), _
                    '            "|", IIf(cmpFormatConditions(cfBase, cfCmp), "True", "False"), "|", _
                    '            iCmp, cfCmp.AppliesTo.Address(, , xlR1C1), cfCmp.Type, _
                    '            Application.ConvertFormula(cfCmp.Formula1, xlA1, xlR1C1, , _
                    '                                       cfCmp.AppliesTo.Cells(1, 1))
                    
                    If (cfCmp.Type = xlCellValue) Or (cfCmp.Type = xlExpression) Then
                        If cmpFormatConditions(cfBase, cfCmp) Then
                            cfBase.ModifyAppliesToRange Union(cfCmp.AppliesTo, cfBase.AppliesTo, cfCmp.AppliesTo)
                            cfCmp.Delete
                            delCount = delCount + 1
                            ' Testing has shown that the .Delete of the extra FormatCondition has caused the
                            ' FormatConditions collection to become changed; e.g., item(1) is no longer
                            ' guaranteed to be the same FormatCondition object that it was prior to the
                            ' .Delete.  So, we will now re-jig the value if iBase so that it restarts at
                            ' item(1) and once once again starts its scan from scratch.
                            iBase = 1
                            GoTo RESTART
                        End If
                    End If
                Next iCmp
            End If
            iBase = iBase + 1
RESTART:
        Loop
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.StatusBar = "Consolidated " & delCount & " FormatCondition records."
End Sub

Private Function cmpFormatConditions(ByRef cfBase As FormatCondition, ByRef cfCmp As FormatCondition, _
                                     Optional ByVal comparePriority As Boolean = False) As Boolean
    Dim rtnVal As Boolean
    
    ' We set the return value (rtnVal) to false, and then test each property.
    ' If any individual test evaluates to false then we fall to the bottom of the if-thens
    ' and return the initial value (false).  If we make it through all the tests, then we
    ' change rtnVal to true before returning.
    '
    ' We test each property in reverse alphabetic order because most of the simple types are then tested
    ' first; which should speed up the code.
    '
    ' NOTE: The Priority property cannot be compared because this is simply the number that reflects
    '       the order in which the FormatCondition records are evaluated.  That said, we do allow this
    '       to behaviour to be overridden through an optional parameter.
    '
    rtnVal = False
    
    If cfBase.Type = cfCmp.Type Then
        ' The specific properties to test is dependent upon the Type.
        Select Case cfBase.Type
            Case xlCellValue, xlExpression
                If cfBase.StopIfTrue = cfCmp.StopIfTrue Then
                    If cfBase.PTCondition = cfCmp.PTCondition Then
                        If (Not comparePriority) Or (comparePriority And cfBase.Priority = cfCmp.Priority) Then
                            If cmpNumberFormat(cfBase.NumberFormat, cfCmp.NumberFormat) Then
                                If cmpInterior(cfBase.Interior, cfCmp.Interior) Then
                                    If Application.ConvertFormula(cfBase.Formula1, xlA1, xlR1C1, , cfBase.AppliesTo.Cells(1, 1)) _
                                          = Application.ConvertFormula(cfCmp.Formula1, xlA1, xlR1C1, , cfCmp.AppliesTo.Cells(1, 1)) Then
                                        If cmpFont(cfBase.Font, cfCmp.Font) Then
                                            If cmpBorders(cfBase.Borders, cfCmp.Borders) Then
                                                rtnVal = True
                                            End If
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
             
             Case Else
                ' Ultimately we need to throw a hard error.
                rtnVal = False
        End Select
    End If
        
    cmpFormatConditions = rtnVal
End Function

Private Function cmpBackground(ByRef bBase As Variant, ByRef bCmp As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim rtnVal As Boolean
    
    rtnVal = False
    
    If IsNull(bBase) And IsNull(bCmp) Then
        rtnVal = True
    ElseIf Not IsNull(bBase) And Not IsNull(bCmp) Then
        If bBase = bCmp Then
            rtnVal = True
        End If
    End If
    
    cmpBackground = rtnVal
End Function

Private Function cmpBold(ByRef bBase As Variant, ByRef bCmp As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim rtnVal As Boolean
    
    rtnVal = False
    
    If IsNull(bBase) And IsNull(bCmp) Then
        rtnVal = True
    ElseIf Not IsNull(bBase) And Not IsNull(bCmp) Then
        If bBase = bCmp Then
            rtnVal = True
        End If
    End If
    
    cmpBold = rtnVal
End Function

Private Function cmpBorder(ByRef bBase As Border, ByRef bCmp As Border) As Boolean
    Dim rtnVal As Boolean

    rtnVal = False
    
    If bBase.Color = bCmp.Color Then
        If bBase.ColorIndex = bCmp.ColorIndex Then
            If Not IsObject(bBase.ThemeColor) And Not IsObject(bCmp.ThemeColor) Then
                rtnVal = True
            ElseIf (Not IsObject(bBase.ThemeColor)) And (Not IsObject(bCmp.ThemeColor)) Then
                If bBase.ThemeColor = bCmp.ThemeColor Then
                    If bBase.Weight = bCmp.Weight Then
                        If bBase.LineStyle = bCmp.LineStyle Then
                            If bBase.TintAndShade = bCmp.TintAndShade Then
                                rtnVal = True
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
    
    cmpBorder = rtnVal
End Function

Private Function cmpBorders(ByRef bBase As Borders, ByRef bCmp As Borders) As Boolean
    Dim rtnVal As Boolean

    rtnVal = False
    
    If cmpBorder(bBase(xlDiagonalDown), bCmp(xlDiagonalDown)) Then
        If cmpBorder(bBase(xlDiagonalUp), bCmp(xlDiagonalUp)) Then
            If cmpBorder(bBase(xlEdgeBottom), bCmp(xlEdgeBottom)) Then
                If cmpBorder(bBase(xlEdgeLeft), bCmp(xlEdgeLeft)) Then
                    If cmpBorder(bBase(xlEdgeRight), bCmp(xlEdgeRight)) Then
                        If cmpBorder(bBase(xlEdgeTop), bCmp(xlEdgeTop)) Then
                            If cmpBorder(bBase(xlInsideHorizontal), bCmp(xlInsideHorizontal)) Then
                                If cmpBorder(bBase(xlInsideVertical), bCmp(xlInsideVertical)) Then
                                    rtnVal = True
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
    
    cmpBorders = rtnVal
End Function

Private Function cmpColor(ByRef cBase As Variant, ByRef cCmp As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim rtnVal As Boolean
    
    rtnVal = False
    
    If IsNull(cBase) And IsNull(cCmp) Then
        rtnVal = True
    ElseIf Not IsNull(cBase) And Not IsNull(cCmp) Then
        If cBase = cCmp Then
            rtnVal = True
        End If
    End If
    
    cmpColor = rtnVal
End Function

Private Function cmpColorIndex(ByRef cBase As Variant, ByRef cCmp As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim rtnVal As Boolean
    
    rtnVal = False
    
    If IsNull(cBase) And IsNull(cCmp) Then
        rtnVal = True
    ElseIf Not IsNull(cBase) And Not IsNull(cCmp) Then
        If cBase = cCmp Then
            rtnVal = True
        End If
    End If
    
    cmpColorIndex = rtnVal
End Function

Private Function cmpFont(ByRef fBase As Font, ByRef fCmp As Font) As Boolean
    Dim rtnVal As Boolean
    
    rtnVal = False
    
    ' Is a Font object and so I need to build out tests for its properties.
    If cmpBackground(fBase.Background, fCmp.Background) Then
        If cmpBold(fBase.Bold, fCmp.Bold) Then
            If cmpColor(fBase.Color, fCmp.Color) Then
                If cmpColorIndex(fBase.ColorIndex, fCmp.ColorIndex) Then
                    If cmpFontStyle(fBase.FontStyle, fCmp.FontStyle) Then
                        If cmpItalic(fBase.Italic, fCmp.Italic) Then
                            If cmpName(fBase.Name, fCmp.Name) Then
                                If cmpSize(fBase.Size, fCmp.Size) Then
                                    If cmpStrikethrough(fBase.Size, fCmp.Size) Then
                                        If cmpSubscript(fBase.Size, fCmp.Size) Then
                                            If cmpSuperscript(fBase.Size, fCmp.Size) Then
                                                If cmpThemeColor_V(fBase, fCmp) Then
                                                    If fBase.ThemeFont = fCmp.ThemeFont Then
                                                        If cmpTintAndShade(fBase.TintAndShade, fCmp.TintAndShade) Then
                                                            If cmpUnderline(fBase.Underline, fCmp.Underline) Then
                                                                rtnVal = True
                                                            End If
                                                        End If
                                                    End If
                                                End If
                                            End If
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
    
    cmpFont = rtnVal
End Function

Private Function cmpFontStyle(ByRef fBase As Variant, ByRef fCmp As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim rtnVal As Boolean
    
    rtnVal = False
    
    If IsNull(fBase) And IsNull(fCmp) Then
        rtnVal = True
    ElseIf Not IsNull(fBase) And Not IsNull(fCmp) Then
        If fBase = fCmp Then
            rtnVal = True
        End If
    End If
    
    cmpFontStyle = rtnVal
End Function

Private Function cmpGradient(ByRef gBase As Variant, ByRef gCmp As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim rtnVal As Boolean
    
    rtnVal = False
    
    If (gBase Is Nothing) And (gCmp Is Nothing) Then
        rtnVal = True
    ElseIf Not (gBase Is Nothing) And Not (gCmp Is Nothing) Then
        If gBase = gCmp Then
            rtnVal = True
        End If
    End If
    
    cmpGradient = rtnVal
End Function

Private Function cmpInterior(ByRef iBase As Interior, ByRef iCmp As Interior) As Boolean
    Dim rtnVal As Boolean
    
    rtnVal = False
    
    If iBase.Color = iCmp.Color Then
        If cmpColorIndex(iBase.ColorIndex, iCmp.ColorIndex) Then
            If cmpGradient(iBase.Gradient, iCmp.Gradient) Then
                If cmpPattern(iBase.Pattern, iCmp.Pattern) Then
                    If cmpPatternColor(iBase.PatternColor, iCmp.PatternColor) Then
                        If cmpPatternColorIndex(iBase.PatternColorIndex, iCmp.PatternColorIndex) Then
                            If cmpPatternThemeColor(iBase.PatternThemeColor, iCmp.PatternThemeColor) Then
                                If cmpPatternTintAndShade(iBase.PatternTintAndShade, iCmp.PatternTintAndShade) Then
                                    If cmpThemeColor_V(iBase, iCmp) Then
                                        If cmpTintAndShade(iBase.TintAndShade, iCmp.TintAndShade) Then
                                            rtnVal = True
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
    
    cmpInterior = rtnVal
End Function

Private Function cmpItalic(ByRef iBase As Variant, ByRef iCmp As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim rtnVal As Boolean
    
    rtnVal = False
    
    If IsNull(iBase) And IsNull(iCmp) Then
        rtnVal = True
    ElseIf Not IsNull(iBase) And Not IsNull(iCmp) Then
        If iBase = iCmp Then
            rtnVal = True
        End If
    End If
    
    cmpItalic = rtnVal
End Function

Private Function cmpName(ByRef nBase As Variant, ByRef nCmp As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim rtnVal As Boolean
    
    rtnVal = False
    
    If IsNull(nBase) And IsNull(nCmp) Then
        rtnVal = True
    ElseIf Not IsNull(nBase) And Not IsNull(nCmp) Then
        If nBase = nCmp Then
            rtnVal = True
        End If
    End If
    
    cmpName = rtnVal
End Function

Private Function cmpNumberFormat(ByRef nfBase As Variant, ByRef nfCmp As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim rtnVal As Boolean
    
    rtnVal = False
    
    If IsEmpty(nfBase) And IsEmpty(nfCmp) Then
        rtnVal = True
    ElseIf (Not IsEmpty(nfBase)) And (Not IsEmpty(nfCmp)) Then
        If nfBase = nfCmp Then
            rtnVal = True
        End If
    End If
    
    cmpNumberFormat = rtnVal
End Function

Private Function cmpPattern(ByRef pBase As Variant, ByRef pCmp As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim rtnVal As Boolean
    
    rtnVal = False
    
    If IsNull(pBase) And IsNull(pCmp) Then
        rtnVal = True
    ElseIf Not IsNull(pBase) And Not IsNull(pCmp) Then
        If pBase = pCmp Then
            rtnVal = True
        End If
    End If
    
    cmpPattern = rtnVal
End Function

Private Function cmpPatternColor(ByRef pBase As Variant, ByRef pCmp As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim rtnVal As Boolean
    
    rtnVal = False
    
    If IsNull(pBase) And IsNull(pCmp) Then
        rtnVal = True
    ElseIf Not IsNull(pBase) And Not IsNull(pCmp) Then
        If pBase = pCmp Then
            rtnVal = True
        End If
    End If
    
    cmpPatternColor = rtnVal
End Function

Private Function cmpPatternColorIndex(ByRef pBase As Variant, ByRef pCmp As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim rtnVal As Boolean
    
    rtnVal = False
    
    If IsNull(pBase) And IsNull(pCmp) Then
        rtnVal = True
    ElseIf Not IsNull(pBase) And Not IsNull(pCmp) Then
        If pBase = pCmp Then
            rtnVal = True
        End If
    End If
    
    cmpPatternColorIndex = rtnVal
End Function

Private Function cmpPatternThemeColor(ByRef pBase As Variant, ByRef pCmp As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim rtnVal As Boolean
    
    rtnVal = False
    
    If IsNull(pBase) And IsNull(pCmp) Then
        rtnVal = True
    ElseIf Not IsNull(pBase) And Not IsNull(pCmp) Then
        If pBase = pCmp Then
            rtnVal = True
        End If
    End If
    
    cmpPatternThemeColor = rtnVal
End Function

Private Function cmpPatternTintAndShade(ByRef pBase As Variant, ByRef pCmp As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim rtnVal As Boolean
    
    rtnVal = False
    
    If IsNull(pBase) And IsNull(pCmp) Then
        rtnVal = True
    ElseIf Not IsNull(pBase) And Not IsNull(pCmp) Then
        If pBase = pCmp Then
            rtnVal = True
        End If
    End If
    
    cmpPatternTintAndShade = rtnVal
End Function

Private Function cmpSize(ByRef sBase As Variant, ByRef sCmp As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim rtnVal As Boolean
    
    rtnVal = False
    
    If IsNull(sBase) And IsNull(sCmp) Then
        rtnVal = True
    ElseIf Not IsNull(sBase) And Not IsNull(sCmp) Then
        If sBase = sCmp Then
            rtnVal = True
        End If
    End If
    
    cmpSize = rtnVal
End Function

Private Function cmpStrikethrough(ByRef sBase As Variant, ByRef sCmp As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim rtnVal As Boolean
    
    rtnVal = False
    
    If IsNull(sBase) And IsNull(sCmp) Then
        rtnVal = True
    ElseIf Not IsNull(sBase) And Not IsNull(sCmp) Then
        If sBase = sCmp Then
            rtnVal = True
        End If
    End If
    
    cmpStrikethrough = rtnVal
End Function

Private Function cmpSubscript(ByRef sBase As Variant, ByRef sCmp As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim rtnVal As Boolean
    
    rtnVal = False
    
    If IsNull(sBase) And IsNull(sCmp) Then
        rtnVal = True
    ElseIf Not IsNull(sBase) And Not IsNull(sCmp) Then
        If sBase = sCmp Then
            rtnVal = True
        End If
    End If
    
    cmpSubscript = rtnVal
End Function

Private Function cmpSuperscript(ByRef sBase As Variant, ByRef sCmp As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim rtnVal As Boolean
    
    rtnVal = False
    
    If IsNull(sBase) And IsNull(sCmp) Then
        rtnVal = True
    ElseIf Not IsNull(sBase) And Not IsNull(sCmp) Then
        If sBase = sCmp Then
            rtnVal = True
        End If
    End If
    
    cmpSuperscript = rtnVal
End Function

Private Function cmpThemeColor_V(ByRef vBase As Variant, ByRef vCmp As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim rtnVal As Boolean
    Dim baseErr, cmpErr As Boolean
    
    baseErr = False
    cmpErr = False
    rtnVal = False
    
    On Error GoTo ERR_BASE
    ' Force an evaluation of fcBase.ThemeColor.  We only care if it was possible to read the property
    ' without generating an error.
    If IsNull(vBase.ThemeColor) Then
        ' Empty clause.
    End If
   
    On Error GoTo ERR_CMP
    ' Force an evaluation of fcBase.ThemeColor.  We only care if it was possible to read the property
    ' without generating an error.
    If IsNull(vCmp.ThemeColor) Then
        ' Empty clause.
    End If
       
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If baseErr And cmpErr Then
        rtnVal = True
    ElseIf (Not baseErr) And (Not cmpErr) Then
        If IsNull(vBase.ThemeColor) And IsNull(vCmp.ThemeColor) Then
            rtnVal = True
        ElseIf Not IsNull(vBase.ThemeColor) And Not IsNull(vCmp.ThemeColor) Then
            If vBase.ThemeColor = vCmp.ThemeColor Then
                rtnVal = True
            End If
        End If
    End If

    cmpThemeColor_V = rtnVal
    Exit Function
    
ERR_BASE:
    On Error Resume Next
    baseErr = True
    Resume
ERR_CMP:
    On Error Resume Next
    cmpErr = True
    Resume
End Function

Private Function cmpTintAndShade(ByRef tbase As Variant, ByRef tcmp As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim rtnVal As Boolean
    
    rtnVal = False
    
    If IsNull(tbase) And IsNull(tcmp) Then
        rtnVal = True
    ElseIf Not IsNull(tbase) And Not IsNull(tcmp) Then
        If tbase = tcmp Then
            rtnVal = True
        End If
    End If
    
    cmpTintAndShade = rtnVal
End Function

Private Function cmpUnderline(ByRef uBase As Variant, ByRef uCmp As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim rtnVal As Boolean
    
    rtnVal = False
    
    If IsNull(uBase) And IsNull(uCmp) Then
        rtnVal = True
    ElseIf Not IsNull(uBase) And Not IsNull(uCmp) Then
        If uBase = uCmp Then
            rtnVal = True
        End If
    End If
    cmpUnderline = rtnVal
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an incomplete attempt to make it as generic as possible (provided as a starting point only)

```
Option Explicit

Private Const SP As String = "||"   'string delimiter, or SeParator

Public Sub x()
    resetConditionalFormatting Sheet1.UsedRange
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Sub resetConditionalFormatting(Optional ByRef rng As Range = Nothing)
    Const FIRST_ROW As Long = 2

    Dim colRng As Range, thisCol As Long, fc As FormatCondition, thisFC As Long
    Dim maxCell As Range, ws As Worksheet, cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range

    If rng Is Nothing Then Set rng = Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set ws = rng.Parent
    Set maxCell = GetMaxCell(rng)

    If maxCell.Row > 1 Or maxCell.Column > 1 Or Len(maxCell) > 0 Then
        thisCol = 1
        Set cell1 = ws.Cells(FIRST_ROW, thisCol)
        Set cell2 = ws.Cells(maxCell.Row, thisCol)
        For Each colRng In rng.Columns
            thisFC = 1
            For Each fc In colRng.FormatConditions
                fc.ModifyAppliesToRange ws.Range(cell1, cell2)
                thisFC = thisFC + 1
            Next
            thisCol = thisCol + 1
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub fcDupe(ByRef fc As Variant, ByRef fcType() As String, ByRef dupes As Long)
    Dim tStr As String, itm As Variant, fcT As Byte

    On Error Resume Next    'some properties may not be defined at runtime
    With fc

        fcT = .Type

    tStr = SP
    'Border, Font, and Interior apply to 1, 2, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 16, 17
    tStr = tStr & CStr(ObjPtr(.Borders)) & _
                  CStr(ObjPtr(.Font)) & _
                  CStr(ObjPtr(.Interior))
    'CStr(ObjPtr(fc)): https://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;199824

        Select Case fcT
            Case xlCellValue                '1
                tStr = tStr & .DateOperator
                tStr = tStr & .Formula1
                tStr = tStr & .Formula2
                tStr = tStr & .Operator
                tStr = tStr & .ScopeType
                tStr = tStr & .Text
                tStr = tStr & .TextOperator
                tStr = tStr & SP
            Case xlColorScale               '3
                tStr = SP & CStr(ObjPtr(.ColorScaleCriteria))
                tStr = tStr & .Formula
                tStr = tStr & .ScopeType
                tStr = tStr & SP
            Case xlDatabar                  '4
                tStr = SP & CStr(ObjPtr(.AxisColor)) & _
                            CStr(ObjPtr(.BarBorder)) & _
                            CStr(ObjPtr(.BarColor)) & _
                            CStr(ObjPtr(.MaxPoint)) & _
                            CStr(ObjPtr(.MinPoint)) & _
                            CStr(ObjPtr(.NegativeBarFormat))
                tStr = tStr & .AxisPosition
                tStr = tStr & .BarFillType
                tStr = tStr & .Direction
                tStr = tStr & .Formula
                tStr = tStr & .PercentMax
                tStr = tStr & .PercentMin
                tStr = tStr & .ScopeType
                tStr = tStr & .ShowValue
                tStr = tStr & SP
            Case xlTop10                    '5
                tStr = tStr & .CalcFor
                tStr = tStr & .Percent
                tStr = tStr & .Rank
                tStr = tStr & .TopBottom
                tStr = tStr & .ScopeType
                tStr = tStr & SP
            Case 6                          'XlFormatConditionType.xlIconSet
                tStr = SP & CStr(ObjPtr(.IconCriteria)) & CStr(ObjPtr(.IconSet))
                tStr = tStr & .Formula
                tStr = tStr & .PercentValue
                tStr = tStr & .ReverseOrder
                tStr = tStr & .ScopeType
                tStr = tStr & .ShowIconOnly
                tStr = tStr & SP
            Case xlUniqueValues             '8
                tStr = tStr & .DupeUnique
                tStr = tStr & .ScopeType
                tStr = tStr & SP
            Case xlTextString               '9
                tStr = tStr & .DateOperator
                tStr = tStr & .Formula1
                tStr = tStr & .Formula2
                tStr = tStr & .Operator
                tStr = tStr & .ScopeType
                tStr = tStr & .Text
                tStr = tStr & .TextOperator
                tStr = tStr & SP
            Case xlAboveAverageCondition    '12
                tStr = tStr & .AboveBelow
                tStr = tStr & .CalcFor
                tStr = tStr & .Formula1
                tStr = tStr & .Formula2
                tStr = tStr & .NumStdDev
                tStr = tStr & SP
            Case xlExpression, _
                 xlBlanksCondition, _
                 xlTimePeriod, _
                 xlNoBlanksCondition, _
                 xlErrorsCondition, _
                 xlNoErrorsCondition
                    tStr = tStr & .Formula1
                    tStr = tStr & .Formula2
                    tStr = tStr & SP
        End Select
        If InStr(1, fcType(fcT), tStr, vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
            fcType(fcT) = fcType(fcT) & tStr
        Else
            .Delete
            dupes = dupes + 1
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Function GetMaxCell(Optional ByRef rng As Range = Nothing) As Range

    'It returns the last cell of range with data, or A1 if Worksheet is empty

    Const NONEMPTY As String = "*"
    Dim lRow As Range, lCol As Range

    If rng Is Nothing Then Set rng = Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) = 0 Then
        Set GetMaxCell = rng.Parent.Cells(1, 1)
    Else
        With rng
            Set lRow = .Cells.Find(What:=NONEMPTY, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                   After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                                   SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                   SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
            Set lCol = .Cells.Find(What:=NONEMPTY, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                   After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                                   SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                   SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)
            Set GetMaxCell = .Parent.Cells(lRow.Row, lCol.Column)
        End With
    End If
End Function
```

A way to see all properties for a specific format condition:

[image]

Comment: Yep! Deeeefinitely an earbuds project. Thanks again Paul! I can tell your methodology is more advanced than what I've worked with before, so I've got some studying to do! What was the reason you abandoned this method? Is it just that the 14 conditional format types are so different from one another that a standardized process produces errors?

Comment: A couple of reasons: 1. I kept you waiting way too long for an answer 2. the proper (generic) solution was getting too complex for a task where conditional formatting is the same in each column - the answer you accepted works well for that and is fairly simple (I can use it as well for some files). The more generic one needs a lot more effort and is likely that for complex conditional formatting it may not work properly even then; it might be safer to just clean it up manually, but maybe you'll find a safe way of doing it :)

Comment: #1: It's odd/awesome that people like you still exist; thanks for being considerate to strangers! I bet you also use a turn signal when merging on a freeway. #2: I **will** find a way! The lit match of your knowledge has landed on the forest of my incorrigibility; and the consequence is unstoppable! (Too soon for forest fire jokes?)

Comment: LOL :) your enthusiasm is admirable!

Comment: Hey Paul, is there a generic way to iterate through a VBA object's members and properties? For instance, I want to iterate through each member and property of FormatConditions and compare it to the corresponding member and/or property in another FormatConditions; when an inconsistency is hit it will start iterating through the next FormatConditions, and when no inconsistency is found after running through all members and properties then it will run a sequence (delete the duplicate and amalgamate the two ranges). Is that a pipe dream?

Comment: When I started, after a few experiments I realized that the best way is to first determine what type of fc you have; after you know the type, you collect all available properties - I collect them in string, separated by the delimiter (||) so I can search the string for the current list. For example if we have an fc with font `||bold||italic||` the next cell might have the same 2 properties (and only these 2). `If InStr(1, fc, ||bold||italic||) = 0` it's not a duplicate so we add the list at the end of the string, but if the string already has this list it's a duplicate so we delete it

Comment: It becomes more complex when fc's are not contiguous, for example: fc for cell A1: bold & italic, fc for A2: font normal, background yellow, A3: bold & italic. Now you have to keep track of the range for the duplicated fc's A1, A3, etc. Let me know if this doesn't make sense or you need more details and we can chat

Comment: Ok see here's my hurdle: A string approach _could_ work if I dedicated a character address to every possibility, but I know the whole utility is going to need to be reprogrammed the moment Microsoft decides to update Excel with a new Conditional Formatting option. (Even something as simple as adding bold outlines to the result format, which I'd love by the way) Buuuuut, if I could take a principled approach instead, like **For Each Property In FormatConditions**, then it would adapt forever! Is there some function in VBA that lists all properties in an object? Or how hard is it to build one?

Comment: Also do you like have WiFi in your head? You're always so quick to respond. Thanks!

Comment: Wait I may have found [something](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms162232(v=SQL.90).aspx). My google searches are becoming more refined as I learn the lingo. To be fair I should try to do this myself first before pestering you anymore. I'll see how far I can go first. Thanks again Paul!

Comment: I added an image to show you how I look at all properties for a format condition; I'm not sure if there is an easier way, but I place a break point when the fc object gets populated, I add it to the watch window, and there you can expand all its properties - there are a lot of nested branches and they are different for each fc type... One other way to store properties might be by using dictionaries, but this can become a big task, quickly

Comment: what you found is relevant for Visual Basic .NET; VBA doesn't work the same way. To iterate through all properties you need to implement a recursive loop that digs into each branch as deep as needed (to the last leaf). First determine if it's a branch (it has any children) and if so check all children if they are branches, continue this checking until you get to a leaf (last child in the branch). Print the single property, go back up one level to the parent and check the rest of its children

Comment: If this parent has only "leafs" (children without their own children) you're at the and of this particular branch; go back up one level to the parent of this parent, and check all its other children the same way. If you have enough memory for a recursive function (I think it can call itself up to around 3,200 times before the stack gets full and throws an error) but if you can traverse the entire tree you'll have to store all properties under in a new new system you define (dictionaries). You may not need to create your own separate storage system, just use fc properties provided by Microsoft

Comment: Well crud. This is starting to seem even more complicated than curing cancer. I wish I didn't have a job so I could _just_ work on this. (Then again I'm doing it _for_ my job so it would be like "The Gift of the Magi" at that point)

Comment: Okay, **crazy** theory here, but what about something like `On Error Resume Next CallByName Replace(StringVariable, chr(v1), chr(v1 + 1), len(StringVariable)-v2,1)` etc. etc. to run through every possible property available in the entire VBA library the same way a password hack basically works? It could create a worksheet, recreate the VBA library, then use it to evaluate the format conditions. It could just build the library once in the Personal Macro book and rebuilt it if there is an error (signifying a change so the library). Crazy? Or crazy enough to work!?

Comment: You're very funny :) Now maybe you understand why I considered the first answer reasonable. About your suggestion I'm not sure I follow: how will you iterate through all properties? (if you have more details you can email me at dexxus at rogers.com)

Comment: Do I ever! It bothers me on like a deep "need to talk to a therapist" level when something is so simple to a human mind, but when it comes to communicating the instructions to a computer it's like explaining color to the blind. I'll shoot you an email about my iteration concept, but the basic method would be calling _every_ possible VBA property by using a chr() loop to try string combinations for like 30 alpha-only characters (which I calculate is over three sexdecillion, so I need to refine the method). Any string that IS a property won't error out, and I could use that list for evaluations.