# How to clean a workbook and reset the last used cell on all sheets

Tags: excel, vba

What is the most reliable and efficient way to trim all sheets of an Excel file of empty formatting?

I consider the Used Range to be all cells with visible data and objects, excluding Comments.

Reliability aspects:

- Preserve all visible data (with its formatting) and formulas on all sheets
- Preserve objects on all sheets: charts, pivot tables, and list objects (data tables)

  - Graphics to remain exactly the same position, size and all other properties after the cleanup
- Remove all blank cells with old formatting or empty strings that generate a "false" Used Range

  - These can be cells that were previously used but their data was removed
  - Invalid formulas, or invisible characters like an untrimmed strings or carriage returns
- The solution should also remove all invalid Names (containing the string "#REF!")
- Cleanup conditional formatting rules on all sheets removing duplicate rules for the same columns
- Clean excess formatting on workbooks and sheets unprotected or protected without a password
- A solution with more coverage than the one provided by Microsoft on this page

  - [How to reset the last cell in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/244435)
  - The code in the Excel Add-in available in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30848369/4914662)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm providing my own attempt to cover the requirements, as a reference

Paste code in a new VBA module and run the first procedure (trimXL)

.

```
Option Explicit

Private pb01 As Boolean, pb02 As Boolean  'protected attribs of WB & WS
Private ps01 As Boolean, ps02 As Boolean, ps03 As Boolean, ps04 As Boolean
Private ps05 As Boolean, ps06 As Boolean, ps07 As Boolean, ps08 As Boolean
Private ps09 As Boolean, ps10 As Boolean, ps11 As Boolean, ps12 As Boolean
Private ps13 As Boolean, ps14 As Boolean, ps15 As Boolean, ps16 As Boolean

Private isWBProtected As Boolean
Private shapeInfo As Object

Public Function trimXL() As Boolean
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, sCnt As Long, shapesOnWS As Long
    Dim lastCel As Range, urAll As Range, thisActWS As Worksheet, isGo As Boolean
    Dim lrAll As Long, lcAll As Long, lrDat As Long, lcDat As Long, msg As String
    Dim emptyRows As Range, emptyCols As Range, sz1 As Single, sz2 As Single

    enableXL False
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    If wbIsReady(wb) Then
        Set thisActWS = wb.ActiveSheet
        removeInvalidNames
        sz1 = FileLen(wb.FullName) / 1024
        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
            isGo = IIf(isWBProtected, canUnprotectWs(ws), True)
            If isGo Then
                Set urAll = ws.UsedRange
                    lrAll = urAll.Rows.Count + urAll.Row - 1
                    lcAll = urAll.Columns.Count + urAll.Column - 1

                If 0 Then unhideRows ws, urAll
                removeXLErrors ws.UsedRange
                trimWhiteSpaces ws
                Set shapeInfo = newDictionary
                shapesOnWS = persistShapesInfo(ws)
                trimListObjects ws

                Set lastCel = GetMaxCell(urAll)
                    lrDat = lastCel.Row
                    lcDat = lastCel.Column

                Set emptyRows = ws.Range(ws.Cells(lrDat + 1, 1), ws.Cells(lrAll + 1, 1))
                Set emptyCols = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, lcDat + 1), ws.Cells(1, lcAll + 1))
                'setStandardSize ws, emptyRows, emptyCols

                If (lrDat = 1 And lcDat = 1) Or (lrAll <> lrDat Or lcAll <> lcDat) Then
                    If lrDat = 1 And lcDat = 1 And Len(lastCel.Value2) = 0 Then
                        urAll.EntireRow.Delete
                        If lrAll <> lrDat Or lcAll <> lcDat Then sCnt = sCnt + 1
                    Else
                        If lrAll <> lrDat Or lcAll <> lcDat Then
                            If lrAll <> lrDat Then emptyRows.EntireRow.Delete
                            If lcAll <> lcDat Then emptyCols.EntireColumn.Delete
                            sCnt = sCnt + 1
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
                If shapesOnWS > 0 Then resetShapesInfo ws
                'resetConditionalFormatting
                If isWBProtected Then protectWs ws
            End If
        Next
        activateFirstCell ws
        thisActWS.Activate
        If isWBProtected Then protectWB wb
        sz2 = FileLen(wb.FullName) / 1024
        'wb.Save
        Set thisActWS = Nothing
        Set shapeInfo = Nothing
    End If
    enableXL

    msg = msg & "     File '" & wb.Name & "' cleaned" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
    msg = msg & "     Size" & vbTab & "Before: " & vbTab & sz1 & " Kb" & vbNewLine
    msg = msg & vbTab & " After: " & vbTab & sz2 & " Kb" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
    msg = msg & vbTab & "Trimmed Sheets" & vbTab & sCnt & vbTab & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
    MsgBox msg, vbInformation, " Trim Completed: """ & wb.Name & """"
End Function



'Sheet Functions -----------------------------------------------------------------------

Private Sub activateFirstCell(ByRef ws As Worksheet)
    If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Application.Goto ws.Cells(1), True
    'ws.Activate: ws.Cells(1).Activate
End Sub

Private Sub setStandardSize(ByRef ws As Worksheet, ByRef eRows As Range, eCols As Range)
    eRows.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = ws.StandardWidth
    eCols.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = ws.StandardWidth
    eRows.EntireRow.RowHeight = ws.StandardHeight
    eCols.EntireRow.RowHeight = ws.StandardHeight
End Sub

Public Sub unhideRows(ByRef ws As Worksheet, ByRef rng As Range)
    If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    If rng Is Nothing Then Set rng = ws.UsedRange
    If Not ws.AutoFilter Is Nothing Then
        With ws.AutoFilter
            If .FilterMode Then If .Filters.Count = 1 Then rng.AutoFilter
        End With
    End If
    rng.Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    rng.Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End Sub

Public Function GetMaxCell(Optional ByRef rng As Range = Nothing) As Range
    'It returns the last cell of range with data, or A1 if Worksheet is empty
    Const NONEMPTY As String = "*"
    Dim lRow As Range, lCol As Range
    If rng Is Nothing Then Set rng = Application.ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) = 0 Then
        Set GetMaxCell = rng.Parent.Cells(1, 1)
    Else
        With rng
            Set lRow = .Cells.Find(What:=NONEMPTY, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                   after:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                                   SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                   SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
            Set lCol = .Cells.Find(What:=NONEMPTY, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                   after:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                                   SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                   SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)
            Set GetMaxCell = .Parent.Cells(lRow.Row, lCol.Column)
        End With
    End If
End Function

Public Sub trimWhiteSpaces(ByRef ws As Worksheet)   'Blanks ----------------------------
    Dim i As Byte
    With ws.UsedRange
        For i = 1 To 10
            .Replace What:=Space(i), Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlWhole
        Next
        .Replace What:=vbTab, Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlWhole
        .Replace What:=vbCrLf, Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlWhole
        .Replace What:=vbCr, Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlWhole
        .Replace What:=vbLf, Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlWhole
        .Replace What:=vbNewLine, Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlWhole
            .Replace What:=vbNullChar, Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlWhole
            .Replace What:=vbBack, Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlWhole
            .Replace What:=vbFormFeed, Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlWhole
            .Replace What:=vbVerticalTab, Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlWhole
            .Replace What:=vbObjectError, Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlWhole
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub trimListObjects(ByRef ws As Worksheet)   'tables
    Dim tbl As ListObject, lastCel As Range, lrDat As Long, lcDat As Long

    For Each tbl In ws.ListObjects
        With tbl
            lcDat = .ListColumns.Count
            If .Range.Count <> (.ListRows.Count * lcDat) Then
                Set lastCel = GetMaxCell(.Range)
                lrDat = lastCel.Row - .Range.Row + 1
                If lrDat = 1 Then .Delete Else .Resize .Range.Resize(lrDat + 1, lcDat)
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub removeXLErrors(ByRef ur As Range)    'All errors ----------------------------
    Dim i As Byte, xlError() As String

    On Error Resume Next
    ur.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).Clear
    If 0 Then
        ReDim xlError(6)
        xlError(0) = "#DIV/0!"      'Excel.XlCVError.xlErrDiv0 = 2007 => #DIV/0!
        xlError(1) = "#N/A"         'Excel.XlCVError.xlErrNA = 2042 => #N/A
        xlError(2) = "#NAME?"       'Excel.XlCVError.xlErrName = 2029 => #NAME?
        xlError(3) = "#NULL"        'Excel.XlCVError.xlErrNull = 2000 => #NULL
        xlError(4) = "#NUM!"        'Excel.XlCVError.xlErrNum = 2036 => #NUM!
        xlError(5) = "#REF"         'Excel.XlCVError.xlErrRef = 2023 => #REF
        xlError(6) = "#VALUE!"      'Excel.XlCVError.xlErrValue = 2015 => #VALUE!
        'VBA.Conversion.CVErr 1 / 0
        'Public Const EXCEL_ERROR        As String = "#N/A"
        For i = 0 To 6
            ur.Replace What:=xlError(i), Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlWhole
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub resetConditionalFormatting(Optional ByRef rng As Range = Nothing)
    Const F_ROW As Long = 2
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ur As Range, maxCol As Long, maxRow As Long, thisCol As Long
    Dim colRng As Range, fcCol As Range, fcCount As Long, fcAdr As String

    If rng Is Nothing Then Set rng = Application.ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set ur = ws.UsedRange
    maxRow = ur.Rows.Count
    maxCol = ur.Columns.Count
    For Each colRng In ws.Columns
        If colRng.Column > maxCol Then Exit For
        thisCol = thisCol + 1
        Set fcCol = ws.Range(ws.Cells(F_ROW, thisCol), ws.Cells(maxRow, thisCol))
        With colRng.FormatConditions
            If .Count > 0 Then
                fcCount = 1
                fcAdr = .Item(fcCount).AppliesTo.Address
                While fcCount <= .Count
                    If .Item(fcCount).AppliesTo.Address = fcAdr Then
                        .Item(fcCount).ModifyAppliesToRange fcCol
                        fcCount = fcCount + 1
                    Else
                        On Error Resume Next
                        .Item(fcCount).Delete
                    End If
                Wend
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub



'Workbook Functions --------------------------------------------------------------------

Public Sub removeInvalidNames()
    Dim itm As Name
    With ThisWorkbook
        If .Names.Count > 0 Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Err.Clear
            For Each itm In .Names
                If InStr(itm.RefersTo, "#REF!") > 0 Then itm.Delete
            Next
        End If
        'xlResetSettings
        .Saved = True
    End With
End Sub



'Shape Functions -----------------------------------------------------------------------

Public Function newDictionary(Optional ByRef dictObj As Object, _
                              Optional ByVal caseSensitive As Boolean = False) As Object
    If Not dictObj Is Nothing Then Set dictObj = Nothing
    'Set dictionaryObject = New Dictionary
    Set dictObj = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dictObj.CompareMode = IIf(caseSensitive, vbBinaryCompare, vbTextCompare)
    Set newDictionary = dictObj
End Function

Private Function persistShapesInfo(ByRef ws As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim sh As Shape, totalShapes As Long
    For Each sh In ws.Shapes
        If Not sh.Type = msoComment Then
            With sh
                shapeInfo(.Name) = .Top & "|" & .Left & "|" & .Height & "|" & .Width
                shapeInfo(.Name) = shapeInfo(.Name) & "|" & .Placement
                .Placement = xlFreeFloating
            End With
            totalShapes = totalShapes + 1
        End If
    Next
    persistShapesInfo = totalShapes
End Function

Private Sub resetShapesInfo(ByRef ws As Worksheet)
    Dim sh As Variant, shInfo As Variant
    For Each sh In shapeInfo
        shInfo = Split(shapeInfo(sh), "|")
        With ws.Shapes(sh)
            .Top = shInfo(0)
            .Left = shInfo(1)
            .Height = shInfo(2)
            .Width = shInfo(3)
            .Placement = shInfo(4)
        End With
    Next
End Sub



'Excel Functions -----------------------------------------------------------------------

Public Sub enableXL(Optional ByVal opt As Boolean = True)
    With Application
        .Calculation = IIf(opt, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
        .DisplayAlerts = opt
        .DisplayStatusBar = opt
        .EnableAnimations = opt
        .EnableEvents = opt
        .ScreenUpdating = opt
    End With
    enableWS , opt
End Sub

Public Sub enableWS(Optional ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal opt As Boolean =True)
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        For Each ws In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
            setWS ws, opt
        Next
    Else
        setWS ws, opt
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub setWS(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal opt As Boolean = True)
    With ws
        .DisplayPageBreaks = False
        .EnableCalculation = opt
        .EnableFormatConditionsCalculation = opt
        .EnablePivotTable = opt
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub xlResetSettings()    'default Excel settings
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .DisplayStatusBar = True
        .EnableAnimations = False
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        Dim sh As Worksheet
        For Each sh In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
            With sh
                .DisplayPageBreaks = False
                .EnableCalculation = True
                .EnableFormatConditionsCalculation = True
                .EnablePivotTable = True
            End With
        Next
    End With
End Sub



'Protection Functions ------------------------------------------------------------------

Private Function wbIsReady(ByRef wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    isWBProtected = wbIsProtected(wb)
    wbIsReady = canUnprotectWb(wb)
End Function

Private Function wbIsProtected(ByRef wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim hasPassword As Boolean, ws As Worksheet
    If Not wb.ReadOnly Then
        pb01 = wb.ProtectStructure
        pb02 = wb.ProtectWindows
        hasPassword = pb01 Or pb02
        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
            hasPassword = hasPassword Or wsIsProtected(ws)
            If hasPassword Then Exit For
        Next
    End If
    wbIsProtected = hasPassword
End Function

Private Function wsIsProtected(ByRef ws As Worksheet) As Boolean
    With ws
        ps01 = .ProtectContents
        ps02 = .ProtectDrawingObjects
        With .Protection
            ps03 = .AllowDeletingColumns
            ps04 = .AllowDeletingRows
            ps05 = .AllowEditRanges.Count > 0
            ps06 = .AllowFiltering
            ps07 = .AllowFormattingCells
            ps08 = .AllowFormattingColumns:
            ps09 = .AllowFormattingRows
            ps10 = .AllowInsertingColumns
            ps11 = .AllowInsertingHyperlinks
            ps12 = .AllowInsertingRows
            ps13 = .AllowSorting
            ps14 = .AllowUsingPivotTables
        End With
        ps15 = .ProtectionMode
        ps16 = .ProtectScenarios
    End With
    wsIsProtected = ps01 Or ps02 Or ps03 Or ps04 Or ps05 Or ps06 Or ps07 Or ps08 Or _
                    ps09 Or ps10 Or ps11 Or ps12 Or ps13 Or ps14 Or ps15 Or ps16
End Function

Private Sub protectWB(ByRef wb As Workbook)
    If Not wb.ReadOnly Then wb.Protect vbNullString, pb01, pb02
End Sub

Private Sub protectWs(ByRef ws As Worksheet)
    ws.Protect vbNullString, ps02, ps01, ps16, True, ps07, ps08, _
               ps09, ps10, ps12, ps11, ps03, ps04, ps13, ps06, ps14
End Sub

Private Function canUnprotectWb(ByRef wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim hasPassword As Boolean

    hasPassword = True
    On Error Resume Next
    wb.Unprotect vbNullString
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        Err.Clear
        hasPassword = True
    End If
    canUnprotectWb = hasPassword
End Function

Private Function canUnprotectWs(ByRef ws As Worksheet) As Boolean
    Dim hasPassword As Boolean

    hasPassword = True
    On Error Resume Next
    ws.Unprotect vbNullString
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        Err.Clear
        hasPassword = False
    End If
    canUnprotectWs = hasPassword
End Function
```

---

More details about cleaning up conditional formatting rules in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31527787/4914662)